# Mockito not generating mocks

Tags: flutter, flutter-mockito, dart-mockito

I had some existing mocks with mockito. I changed the names of some classes that had been mocked and now mockito doesn't generate mocks for them anymore.

An example is:

```
import 'package:mockito/annotations.dart';
import 'package:vepo/src/presentation/pages/manage_vegan_items/page/helpers/manage_vegan_items_page_vm.dart';

@GenerateMocks([ManageVgnItmsPageVm])
void main() {}
```

It is imported without error. After running `flutter pub run build_runner build`, no mocks have been generated for the newly named classes. The app runs fine. Does anyone know what might have caused mockito not to generate the mock files?

Comment: Just to be safe, try adding `--delete-conflicting-outputs` after `build_runner build`. You could try that first.

Answer (score 2):

[It worked when I moved the mock in the question to the test/ directory](https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/issues/536#issuecomment-1197578112)